# error when trying npm install ent

Tags: node.js

When "npm install ent" (on win8.1 and win2003) it fire error:

```
C:\inner>npm install ent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ent/-/ent-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ent/-/ent-0.1.0.tgz

> ent@0.1.0 prepublish c:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4436-heZG7-o8\ent-0
.1.01385483210773-0.007000790908932686\package
> node build/index.js


module.js:333
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4436-heZG7-o8\e
nt-0.1.01385483210773-0.007000790908932686\package\build\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
    at startup (node.js:123:16)
    at node.js:1027:3
npm ERR! addLocalDirectory Could not pack "c:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Tem
p\\npm-4436-heZG7-o8\\ent-0.1.01385483210773-0.007000790908932686\\package" to "
C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\ent\\0.1.0\\package.tgz"
npm ERR! ent@0.1.0 prepublish: `node build/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ent@0.1.0 prepublish script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ent package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build/index.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ent
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ent"
npm ERR! cwd C:\inner
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.9
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\inner\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! 

not ok code 0
```

It is try to execute script from non exist directory "build".

I need this pkg for "npm install nodemailer", it is fire error too when install, becouse "ent" cant install properly.

Comment: `This is most likely a problem with the ent package`. Ask the developers about this issue.

Comment: Try [`npm install he`](http://mths.be/he) — it’s a more robust alternative to `ent`.